# Как проверить, является ли выбранный элемент последним элементом в списке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как проверить, является ли выбранный элемент с классом `one` последним элементом с классом `one`?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">1</td>
        <td class="two">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">3</td>
        <td class="two">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">5</td>
        <td class="two">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">7</td>
        <td class="two">8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.one', function() {
    if ($(this) == $('.one:last')) {//нужно подправить
        console.log("yes")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.one', function() {
    if ($(this).is('.one:last')) {
        console.log("yes");
    }
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">1</td>
        <td class="two">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">3</td>
        <td class="two">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">5</td>
        <td class="two">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">7</td>
        <td class="two">8</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Если элементы с классом `.one` являются статичными на странице, то несколько лучше (в плане быстродействия) будет использовать такой вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $elements = $('.one');
    var lastElement = $elements[$elements.length - 1];
    $elements.on('click', function() {
        if (this == lastElement) {
            console.log("yes");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">1</td>
        <td class="two">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">3</td>
        <td class="two">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">5</td>
        <td class="two">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">7</td>
        <td class="two">8</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```